# jQuery get visible table cells' values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have a table that looks something like  this, where most of the rows are not displayed:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header1</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display:none;">
            <td>content1</td>
            <td>content2</td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:none;">
            <td>content1</td>
            <td>content2</td>
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content1</td>
            <td>content2</td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to access all of the visible rows in the table, and concatenate each cells' value to a string that will be output into CSV. I have some jQuery code but it doesn't get very far at the moment:

```
<input type="button" value="Export" id="csv-export" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#csv-export").click(function () {
            var csvStr = "";
            $("#myTable tr:visible td").each(function () {   //for each td in each visible row
                if ($(this).has("a") == false) {   //if the td does not contain a link
                    csvStr += $(this).html();   //Append the td's html
                }
            });
            $.get('@Url.Action("CSVExport")', { csv: csvStr });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The line `$("#myTable tr:visible td").each(function () {` is failing. Any help here? I'm a bit of an amateur at writing this type of code. I want this code to select all `tr` elements that are not set to `display: none` and then for each of these, select and access all `td` elements.

Comment: When you say the line is failing, what do you mean? Are you getting a JS error? Or is it simply not running for anything?

Comment: @Jacob When I step into the line, it skips to the `$.get` at the end and doesn't even make it to the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.has()` method returns a jQuery object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, `has` unlike `hasClass` method doesn't return a boolean value, it's a filtering method, you should use `length` property instead:

```
if (!$(this).find("a").length) {
```

If you want to exclude `td` elements that have `a` descendants, you can use `.not()` method:

```
$("#myTable tr:visible td").not(":has(a)").each(function () {
```

In case that you want to create a comma-seprated-values string, you can use `.map()` method:

```
var csvString = $("#myTable tr:visible td").not(":has(a)").map(function() {
     return $.trim( $(this).text() );
}).get().join();
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Led6b/)***

The issue you are having is that has<sup>[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/has/)</sup> will return a collection. In order to get a truthy value out of it, you should check the length property.

```
if (!$(this).has("a").length) {  
 csvStr += $(this).html();
}
```

Otherwise, everything else works just fine.